# select2 - json data not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" style="width:300px" id="search"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search').select2({ data:[{id:1,text:'hello'},{id:2,text:'select2'}] });
  });
</script>
```

**Result:**

[image: Select2 Empty]

**select2 version:**
3.5.1

Comment: data:[{id:1,text:'hello'},{id:2,text:'select2'}]  <- this is the correct obj format

Answer (score 0):

Your object is malformed -

```
{ data:[{id=1,text='hello'},{id=2,text='select2'}] }
```

Should be

```
{ data:[{id:1,text:'hello'},{id:2,text:'select2'}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

In html

```
          <div>
             <input type="hidden" style="width:300px" id="search"/>
          </div>
```

In Javascript

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#search').select2({ data:[{id:1,text:'hello'},{id:2,text:'select2'}] });
     });
 </script>
```

I have tried the same code you are using in fiddle and it was working...
http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/4321/

Comment: damn man, I copy pasted that code in the app and its still the same.

Comment: I told that i copied and pasted your code and it was working in fiddle...I didnt include or modify anything...So, something was missing in your app...

Comment: I haven't been able to fix it yet. There is no error or anything in the console. I will tell you when i find it.